# How to draw the Postgis Shortest_path line on google maps?

Tags: postgresql, google-maps, postgis

I have installed PostGIS/PostgreSQL, imported the OSM data from OpenStreetMaps and I am querying the database to get shortest path between two points. As is visible on image the query returns the nodes in the way between the points, however, the query returns just nodes and I need to draw the way on Map (**Google map**). Does anybody know how can I draw the way based on these nodes (latitude, longitude)?

[image: Screenshot of executed query]

```
SELECT * FROM shortest_path('
      SELECT id AS id,
          source::int4 AS source,
          target::int4 AS target,
          cost::float8 AS cost
      FROM br_2po_4pgr',
      1,
      5110,
      false,
      false)
```

It returns all coordinates between the source and target, but each line has two pairs of latitude and longitude (x1,y1 and x2,y2).. I don't know which one I have to use..

thanks!

Comment: That screenshot is kind of hard to see. You might want to consider pasting your query and a couple of sample rows directly into the question instead.

Answer (score 2):

Actually the screenshot size is fine.  One just has to load it standalone in the browser.  What's lacking in the screentshot is that the last column name is truncated.  That's the actual geom.  All you have to do is convert that geom to `KML` with PostGIS's `ST_AsKML` and then [load it on Google Maps like this](http://www.askdavetaylor.com/how_to_import_xml_kml_data_file_google_maps.html).  Do a little research on `KML`.